# Order by in Rails adding it's own order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

In the [Rails tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering), it says that I can simply use `.order("something")` and it'd work. However, when I write `Course.order("name DESC")` I get the query:

`SELECT "courses".* FROM "courses" ORDER BY name ASC, name DESC`

When I really want (notice that it's just ordered by `name DESC`):

`SELECT "courses".* FROM "courses" ORDER BY name DESC`

How could I force it through?

Comment: Have a look at your app/models/order.rb. Do you have anything called "default_scope"?

Comment: Yes there is, how do I override it? It says `default_scope :order => 'name ASC'`

Comment: Yuck! :-) Well you CAN override it using "with_exclusive_scope". But it is better not to use default_scope in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, @CarstenGehling. Yes this problem does appear to be code smell  and I can see why using it was bad to begin with (just look at the problem I had here). Just for future reference, it's code smell because developers often forget about the scoping and also because models shouldn't really be dealing with view logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because I was using `default_scope` in the model that caused it. Running this avoids the scoping:

`Course.unscoped.order("name DESC")`

Edit: for future reference this is code smell and `default_scope` should be used carefully because often developers will forget (months after writing code) that `default_scope` is set and bite you back.

Answer (score 4):

if you have a default order befined by a `default_scope`, you can override by using `reorder`

```
Order.reorder('name DESC')
```

UPDATE:  Using `unscoped` will also work but be wary that this totally removes all scopes defined on the query.  For example, the following will all return the same sql

```
Order.where('id IS NOT NULL').unscoped.order('name DESC')
Order.unscoped.order('name DESC')
Order.scope1.scope2.unscoped.order('name DESC')
current_user.orders.unscoped.order('name DESC')
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please kindly explain why. I see nothing problematic here.

Comment: Unfortunately not even moderators can see vote history (and I'm not a mod) but it's pretty rude to downvote a non-obvious case w/o an explanation. Shrug and move on I guess.